# Hide an element (box/tabs) in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a shiny dashboard which has a just a single text box on the landing page. The user enters an emailid which displays relevant data. This works fine. However I need a box/ tab Panel that greets the user on reaching the page and disappears when the user begins to enter text(emailid) in the text input. Is this possible?

```
output$introbox=renderUI(box(h3("Welcome to the page. Please enter your email id to proceed")),
                                conditionalPanel(condition=input.emailid=="")
```

The box is displayed on landing on the page but doesn't disappear on entering text.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you want, but take a look at `shinyjs::toggle` (or `shinyjs::hide` and `shinyjs::show`), maybe it'll help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oskar's answer is correct. But it does not actually use shinyjs, it includes all the JavaScript manually. You can use his answer, but here is a rewrite of his answer using shinyjs

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    div(id = "greetbox-outer",
      box( id ="greetbox",
           width  = 12, 
           height = "100%",
           solidHeader = TRUE, 
           status = "info",
           div(id="greeting", "Greeting here") 
      )
    ),
    box( id ="box",
         width  = 12, 
         height = "100%",
         solidHeader = TRUE, 
         status = "success",

         textInput("txtbx","Enter text: ")
    )
      )
    )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$txtbx,{
    if (input$txtbx == "") return(NULL)
    hide(id = "greetbox-outer", anim = TRUE)
    print(input$txtbx)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How this can be extended to server option, I want to hide option for particular user?

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible and as daattali sugested shinyjs can help you with some standard Javascript tasks.

If you want to hide the shinydashboard `box` element you have to (from what I know) use some custom Javascript like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(
      tags$script(
        HTML("
        Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ('hide',function (selector) {
          $(selector).parent().slideUp();
        });"
        )
      )
    ),
    box( id ="greetbox",
         width  = 12, 
         height = "100%",
         solidHeader = TRUE, 
         status = "info",
         div(id="greeting", "Greeting here") 
    ),
    box( id ="box",
         width  = 12, 
         height = "100%",
         solidHeader = TRUE, 
         status = "success",

         textInput("txtbx","Enter text: ")
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$txtbx,{
    if (input$txtbx == "") return(NULL)
    session$sendCustomMessage (type="hide", "#greetbox")
    print(input$txtbx)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The html layout for the box looks like:

```
<div class="box box-solid box-info">
    <div class="box-body" id="greetbox">
        <!-- Box content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And since we want to hide the whole box we have to hide the parent element to the id set in the box function, hence the jQuery snippet.

Comment: Good answer, though you're doing all the javascript yourself. I added another answer that builds on yours and just replaces the javascript with shinyjs

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and my problem was with `box()`: if I changed `box()` to `div()`, then the show/hide options worked perfectly.

This solution is simpler, yet not so *elegant* as modifying the tags. Simply wrap your `box()` on a `div()` like this:

```
div(id = box1, box(...))
div(id = box2, box(...))
```

Then, you call to show/hide using the `div`'s id.

Comment: Thanks for this! Small but very important detail! Without it, a part of the box might still show!