# Web application which runs R

Tags: r, shiny

I have written my R script with some functions to do some calculations. On the output of my calculations, I have created plots in shiny(4 tab panels in that as of now, which is using the data specified in my global.R). Now I am trying to automate the process and deliver it to non technical users. So something like, users feed in 2 csv files in web UI and click a button in the web UI, which will then call my r scripts to do the calculations, then my server.R script should build plots on the output of it. Any similar examples? I tried different links, but nothing seems to be relevant.

1. If I add my R script using source(**.R) and use the functions mentioned in there. Or Do I still have to save output in data folder and specify something in global.R or just use the output of the function in my plot construction?
2. If I have the fileInput option in first tab in my tabpanels, how can I make stop the user from viewing the other tabs(tabs with graphs) without loading the input csv files and clicking the "Go" button?
3. Can I do this whole thing in Shiny ? Or better to go for rook or some other framework which calls my r script just for calculations?

Comment: All this should be possible within shiny

Comment: Thats great and thanks for that. Any example or tutorial link which will help me to start?

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Comment: Yes i checked this, but it doesn't call any external scripts, also not the other tabs are waiting for the input file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703241/activate-tabpanel-from-another-tabpanel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027756/hide-an-element-box-tabs-in-shiny-dashbaord

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps, i will read it and try to build my own. Is there anything which is related my first question? Or anything which helps me to call my function in external script based on button click in first tab?

Comment: no just use your function